# Processing: For-loop, ellipses in diagonal lines

Tags: for-loop, processing, ellipse

I'm almost there with an exercise, which I have to do for class.
I'm supposed to make a single for loop creating ellipses in diagonal lines. My code shows that, however I cant figure out why the last ellipse in the top-right corner is not showing.. what am I missing?

```
size(400,400);

for( int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
{

  ellipse(0 + x * 200 , 0 + x * 200 , 50, 50);
  ellipse(0 + x * 200, 400 + x * 200, 50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think about what your two `ellipse()` statements are doing:

`ellipse(0 + x * 200 , 0 + x * 200 , 50, 50);`: This one draws an ellipse at the upper-left corner, then an ellipse in the center, then an ellipse in the lower-right corner.

`ellipse(0 + x * 200, 400 + x * 200, 50, 50);`: This one draws an ellipse in the lower-left corner. But then the other 2 ellipses it draws will be below the edge of the screen!

Remember that the Y values start at zero at the top of the window.

Try using `println()` statements inside your for loop to really understand what's going on. If you still can't solve your problem, try doing this without a for loop first. Can you just call the `ellipse()` function 5 times? When you have that working, then look at the coordinates you're passing in until you see a pattern that you can use inside a for loop.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense that they are drawn out of the screen, however we just tried to do the math, and we cant get it right. I wanted to divide the number so that is the y-axes becomes 200 and then 0, but I cant since the x-value is 0. That made it hard to keep testing theories.

Comment: I recommend drawing out some examples. What do you want your y-value to be for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: I want the y-value to start at 400 in the bottom-left corner, then divide it by two = 200 and then again to 0. I just dont know how to write that

Comment: And what is the value of your loop variable (x in this case) for each of those y values?

Comment: So you've got 0:400, 1:200 and 2:0. Do you see a pattern? Hint: You're starting at 400, so maybe you want to **subtract** something from that for each iteration instead of trying to divide it?

Comment: Haha, thanks! I just put a () around x*200 and made the subtraction - math is a bit far away right now

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit confusing because there are different ways to do the same thing. So far it looks like your familiar with loops which is great.

The only thing that looks like it's missing is working out the reverse of a value.

You count from 0 to 2 inclusive:

```
for( int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
```

which gives you x with values `0,1,2` which is useful when drawing the top left to bottom right diagonal, since that matches the coordinate system (0,0 at top left).

To draw a diagonal from bottom left to top right you need different values
so instead of

```
(0,0)
(1,1)
(2,2)
```

you will need:

```
(0,2)
(1,1)
(2,0)
```

One way to get the reverse value within a range is to subtract a value within the range from the maximum value of that range.

Here's a very basic sketch to illustrate the concept:

```
strokeWeight(10);//make points large/easy to see
int max = 2;
for(int x = 0 ; x <= max; x++){
  float offset = x * 25;//spacing of 25

  int reverseX = max - x;
  float reverseOffset = reverseX * 25; 
  println("iteration " + x + " inverse iteration value: " + reverseX + " offset: " + offset + " reverseOffset: " + reverseOffset); 

//  point(offset,offset);
  point(reverseOffset,offset);
}
```

Another option is to use two counters in your for loop.
Hopefully your assignment doesn't consider this a cheat and it may look more confusing, but it's not too bad.

```
for(int x = 0, y = 3 ; x <= 3; x++, y--){

  println("iteration " + x + " reverse iteration: " + y); 

  point(x * 25,y * 25);
}
```

The only parts in the for loop that changed are the first (initialization) and last (iteration) steps. You're initializing 2 variables instead of one:

1. First variable starts at 0
2. Second variables starts with the maximum values

In the increment step, you're handling two variables:

1. First variable goes up (increments with ++)
2. Second variable goes down (decrements with --)